# How to dynamically add Text box for user input form to C# GUI?

Tags: c#, user-interface

At the beginning, I want the user to enter a number in the appearing GUI - for example 5.

Then I would like the GUI to show a 5x5 area filled with Text Boxes (25 of it) that will accept input from the user - is it possible to do that?

And how to handle tan input from each field?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Then it depends on what UI Platform you're using. You didn't say.

Comment: @Jimi I'm using Net Core 3.1, but I can change it to Net 5.0 if necessary.

Comment: Didn't mention the .Net version, but the UI Platform: WinForms / WPF / UWP / Xamarin etc. -- In any case, either use .Net Framework (WinForms / WPF) or .Net 5 (Any).

Comment: @Jimi Oh, sorry. I'm using WinForms.

Comment: Add a TableLayoutPanel to your Form, set `AutoSize = true`. When a User enters a number (assume in a TextBox named `userInput.Text`), define the Rows / Columns of the TableLayoutPanel, then loop the number of times specified: `if (int.TryParse(userInput.Text, out int howMany)) { tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = howMany; tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = howMany; for (int i = 0; i < howMany * howMany; i++) var txt = new TextBox() tableLayoutPanle1.Controls.Add(txt); }`.

Comment: All Columns and Rows Styles of your TableLayoutPanel set to `AutoSize`.

Comment: "And how to handle tan input from each field?"  As you create them dynamically, add them to a 2D Array, or a List of Lists?  Or give them a unique name as you create them, perhaps based on row/col, and add them to a Dictionary?  You can also add event handlers to those controls as you create them.